# Looking for learning material

Tags: operating-system

I'm studying operating systems with [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471694665) and following some exercise guides from the university: scheduling, synchronization, memory, file system, I/O...

It's an interesting topic, but I've to take the exam in a month so I've a short amount of time to deeply learn it. I tried reading a [linux scheduler](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/The_Original_Process_Scheduler) for example, but I couldn't understand it very well because of my limited C knowledge.

I'm looking for comprehensive material(interactive at best), I've found this about [semaphores(synchronization)](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/) that seems really nice and I'm about to start looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is, in addition to search for some interactive learning solutions, to read some chapters of [Modern Operating Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639) book by A. S. Tanenbaum

I studied it for Operating Systems and Architecture course (@ university - Computer Science, 2nd year) and it's very good as the author makes concepts simple to understand!